# В шаблоне навигация на латинице. Сменил на русский, и пропали фото

Tags: html, css, link, navigation

Теперь более подробно.
В шаблоне есть меню навигации по категориям. Я изменил название категорий с английского на русский, и в категориях пропали фотографии. Т.е. открывается пустая страница. Стоит сменить обратно на английский язык текст кнопок, как фотографии снова работают. Я уже полазил в CSS, в JS, но не смог найти решение проблемы.
Код меню навигации выглядит так:

```html
<div class="tm-paging-links">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link active">Двери</a></li>
      <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link">Окна</a></li>
      <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link">Лестницы</a></li>
      <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link">Изготовление</a></li>
      <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link">Реставрация</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Оригинал (с английским) выглядит так:

```html
<div class="tm-paging-links">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link active">Doors</a></li>
      <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link">Windows</a></li>
      <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link">Stairs</a></li>
      <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link">Craft</a></li>
      <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link">Restoration</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Т.е. сменив латиницу на русский, у меня пропадают фотографии в этих категориях.
Помогите пожалуйста.
Если вопрос немного сумбурный - простите. Ночь уж на дворе)
UPD:
Движок html. Я не работаю сейчас пока в CMS.
Фрагмент кода с первой страницей галереи:

```
<div class="tm-paging-links">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link active">Двери</a></li>
            <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link">Окна</a></li>
            <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link">Лестницы</a></li>
            <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link">Изготовление</a></li>
            <li class="tm-paging-item"><a href="#" class="tm-paging-link">Реставрация</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<!-- Gallery -->
<div class="row tm-gallery">
    <!-- gallery page 1 -->
    <div id="tm-gallery-page-doors" class="tm-gallery-page">
        <article class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 tm-gallery-item">
            <figure>
                <img src="img/gallery/01.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid tm-gallery-img" />
                <figcaption>
                    <h4 class="tm-gallery-title">Сталинские двери</h4>
                    <p class="tm-gallery-description">Описание</p>
                    <p class="tm-gallery-price">Цена</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </article>
        <article class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 tm-gallery-item">
            <figure>
                <img src="img/gallery/02.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid tm-gallery-img" />
                <figcaption>
                    <h4 class="tm-gallery-title">Межкомнатные двери</h4>
                    <p class="tm-gallery-description">Описание</p>
                    <p class="tm-gallery-price">Цена</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </article>                  
    </div>
    <!-- gallery page 1 -->
```

Надеюсь это сможет прояснить ситуацию? Если нет, скажите, чем можно дополнить мой вопрос. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А в каком движке (CMS) это происходит? Лучше дополните вопрос, без этого ответ Вам, скорее всего, не смогут дать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Конкретно связи между языком пунктов меню в навигации и тем что у Вас не открываются фото как таковой нет, нельзя что-то конкретное сказать по коду который Вы привели. Разве что где-то захардкожена привязка названий пунктов меню к каким-то конкретным страницам, так как везде в атрибуте `href` решетка, а не ссылка на какую-то конкретную страницу. Ну и в принципе не ясно что из себя представляют категории и так далее.

Comment: Могу скинуть код одной из категорий, поскольку я ещё форматирую шаблон)